# How do I create a clickable grid of hours in a week, saving clicks to MySQL?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Just wondering if there is a system out there that will basically allow for the following :

[image: Clickable]

Displaying a grid of hours in a week that a user can click on to select and reclick to deselect and when the form is submitted it will send the blocks off to MySQL to store.

Since I havent done this before Im not sure on the best course of action, intial thoughts were to load up a pixel.gif and use onclick to tally clicks but before I reinvent the wheel as a square I thought it best to ask questions first to save trouble later.

Comment: Do you want to know how to draw that grid or how to send that data to sql or how to store that data (database architecture)?

Comment: Hi Janis, I could attempt it with onclicks, 5x5 pixel gif files and arrays but Ive read so many Questions on here that Id answer in a long drawn out way to be shown such a simpler and more elegant solution I thought it best to ask if anyone had seen something similar to this type of question before and there was an existing piece of code I could look at.

Comment: "5x5 pixel gif files...". If you do it the .gif way, you won't need more than 2 gif files - 1 that represents "clicked" state and the other "not clicked".

Comment: Hey Janis, yeah thats what I thought. Now got something working quite nicely, Ill post back once its complete :)

Comment: Ill try and add in my answer at the bottom for the reference of anyone else who in future is looking for something similar. I only asked in case someone knew of an existing method and I didnt want to reinvent the wheel. However it turned out to be fairly ok to put together :)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a table where the checked td's have one class and the unchecked td's have another class, and all of them have a unique ID. Then set the onclick action for each of the two classes to send the id of the td as an argument to a javascript function that uses ajax to update the database and changes the class of the td to selected or unselected.

The html would look like:

```
<td id='19_09_2011_12am' class='unselected_td'/></td>
<td id='19_09_2011_12am' class='selected_td'/></td>
```

The css would look like:

```
.unselected_td{background-color:blue;}
.selected_td{background-color:yellow;}
```

And the javascript:

```
$('.unselected_td').click(function(){
   var cell = this.id;
  $.ajax({
   type:'post',
   url:'path/file.php',
   data:"cell="+cell+"&checked=1",
   success:function(){
      $(this).removeClass('unselected_td').addClass('selected_td');
   }
 });
});
```

And vice-versa for the selected ones, sending a 0 to the server instead. I'm not 100% sure about the syntax I used in the jquery, but the idea of this should work

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to achieve this would be to use buttons or checkboxes to represent the dates/hours selected. Checkboxes would be the simplest, since they could just be set to a value of '1', and only the selected checkboxes would show up as `$_POST` variables when you submit the form.

Buttons could have more style applied to them, but you would have to use some javascript code to toggle the value and style of the button when it's clicked. This is very easy to do in jQuery.

Comment: I was thinking something along those lines, or onclicks on image place holders. Just wanted to check I wasnt doing something silly. Been readying dailywtf.com too much and now scared to make programming errors LOL

Comment: I think you should start with checkboxes first. It is super easy to implement with all you need functionality. Changing it to a more advanced "fancy" feature will not be so hard if you assign them the same id's.